# OrientDB large data count of filed slow response?

Tags: orientdb, database-performance, query-performance

We have inserted 15 million records to orientdb for huge data query performance testing purpose.

System Configuration: Linux, 2Cpu & 4GB Ram

```
var X;
for(var i=1;i<15000000;i++)
{
  X='insert into customer set id='+i+',name=\'SENTHIL'+i+'\',age='+i;
  db.command(X);

}
```

DB/Collection Picture:
[image: DB/Collection Picture]

DB Index Picture
[image: DB Index Picture]

Where try to fetch records as like below we got slow response

```
select count(age) from customer where age > 100000 and age < 999999
```

Query executed in 7.652 sec

```
select count(age) from customer where age > 1000000 and age < 9999999
```

Query executed in 183.465 sec.

```
explain select count(age) from customer where age > 1000000 and age < 9999999

+ FETCH FROM INDEX customerAge
  age > 1000000 and age < 9999999
+ EXTRACT VALUE FROM INDEX ENTRY
  filtering clusters [25,26,27,17,16,19,18,21,20,23,22,24,15]
+ FILTER ITEMS BY CLASS 
  customer
+ CALCULATE PROJECTIONS
  age AS _$$$OALIAS$$_1
+ CALCULATE AGGREGATE PROJECTIONS
      count(_$$$OALIAS$$_1) AS _$$$OALIAS$$_0
+ GUARANTEE FOR ZERO COUNT 
+ CALCULATE PROJECTIONS
  _$$$OALIAS$$_0 AS `count(age)`
```

How we can fix slow response?

Comment: If your main concern is latency and ingest throughput I suggest you'll check redistimeseries.io

Answer (score 0):

my first impression of OrientDB was similar. The DB seemed to perform worse than a conventional relational database. After experiments with slighty improved queries, which simulated RDBMS behavior, slowly I moved away from the »relational thinking«.

For me, the benefits of OrientDB emerged after reorganizing the data. As I deal with time-related data, I decided, first to create a powerful Search-framework: a time-graph (https://github.com/topofocus/orientdb_time_graph). By assigning structured and unstructured data to the grid I am able to access anything very quickly if only I have an idea of the timeframe. The better the guess, the quicker the response.

What I learned: Its even more important to organize the data well in a graph-database then in a relational one.

To reduce the response-time, I suggest to cluster the data during input, put small-ages in a class small, ... and so on. As a result, you can always fire a query on the hole dataset (select from customer), but if you know the age boundary of your child-class, you (or better: the database-engine)  can focus on that.